# NGINX cookie free domain config setup small issue

Tags: linux, cookies, nginx, cdn

I have bought this domain --> cdnwknet.com to be my cookie free domain. I would like to serve static content from it.

All I need to do is to set it up correctly. At the moment it does not work as I want it to work. I have put images on that domain which can be viewed here --> cdnwknet.com/img/index.php. I am only displaying the images in that folder of IMG using scandir so the images are in that folder on that domain.

I tested to call the images from my site --> https://www.damircalusic.se/portfolio/ and than I ran GTMETRIX to see if they are served as static images but they were not as you can see in this report --> http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.damircalusic.se/YGFX2COr and under YSLOW, CDN.

So my simple question is: How do I config the cdnwknet.com domain?

I would really appreciate any help with this!

My config looks like this at the moment:

```
 server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   servername cdnwknet.com www.cdnwknet.com;
   addheader Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
   return 301 https://www.cdnwknet.com$request_uri;
 }

 server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name cdnwknet.com;

   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/KEY.key;

   return 301 https://www.cdnwknet.com$request_uri;
 }

 server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.cdnwknet.com;
   root /var/www/cdnwknet.com/html;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/KEY.key;

   error_page 403 /error/403.html;
   error_page 404 /error/404.html;

   include /etc/nginx/general-top.conf;

   if ( $request_uri ~ ^(/index\.php)$ ) {
      return 301 https://www.cdnwknet.com;
   }

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      expires max;

      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

      tcp_nodelay off;
      break;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
      fastcgi_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }

   location = /error/403.html {
      root /var/www/cdnwknet.com/html;
      allow all;
   }

   location = /error/404.html {
      root /var/www/cdnwknet.com/html;
      allow all;
  } 
 }
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your configuration. A **C**ontent **D**elivery **Network** is not a dummy server behind an additional domain you just bought on Namecheap. It's a complex system based on anycast using BGP announcements from multiple locations in the world and synchonizing content between datacenters.

The purpose of this is to provide better user experience by serving requests from the closest geographical place possible to get rid of excessive Round Trip Time for users physically too far away from your servers thus suffering high loading times. You need to afford this service from a third party if you don't have the (big) infrastructure at your disposal to host it yourself.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to make it a cookie free domain? I am just trying to make a simple cookie free domain and have all images for my 3 websites on it and just call on them with no cookies like I am calling on them on --> https://www.damircalusic.se/portfolio/.

For my needs I do not need a real CDN just a cookie free domain. I have googled alot and tested alot of codesnippets but I can't figure it out yet. 

Many tutorials etc. have the static files remian on their main site while calling the cookie free domain and just rerouting the static via the cookie free domain. That would be ideal.

Comment: @damircalusic Move the `fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie` directive to the location using `fastcgi_pass`... Btw your [**cipher suites**](http://serverfault.com/questions/637848/how-to-mitigate-poodle-but-keep-sslv3-support-for-old-clients) are completely broken.

Comment: Thank you @Xavier Lucas for the SSL issue, I have fixed it now. I have also moved the the Set-Coookie below fastcgi_pass. You can look at the edited version above. Was it like this you meant?

Comment: @damircalusic Yes it looks ok to me (if you have put the right ciphers ofc).

Comment: Okay thank you @Xavier Lucas. I have put the ciphers in the main config instead of it being in sites-available config. The SSL works great now and I have an A on the testlabs. Thank you also for your input regarding the main issue with cookies. :)